# Conan libbacktrace package requiring wrong autoconf version

Tags: conan

When I try to `conan install libbacktrace` on `CentOS` with `gcc 10.2`, it fails with an error message saying that the `autoconf` version is incorrect.

```
conan install libbacktrace/cci.20210118@ --build=missing


Configuration:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=10.2
os=Linux
os_build=Linux
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]

Installing package: libbacktrace/cci.20210118
Requirements
    libbacktrace/cci.20210118 from 'conan-center' - Cache
Packages
    libbacktrace/cci.20210118:30b88e95da2480aa597d26d85ba6f64038dcf40f - Build
Build requirements
    autoconf/2.71 from 'conan-center' - Cache
    automake/1.16.3 from 'conan-center' - Cache
    libtool/2.4.6 from 'conan-center' - Cache
    m4/1.4.18 from 'conan-center' - Cache
Build requirements packages
    autoconf/2.71:cb054d0b3e1ca595dc66bc2339d40f1f8f04ab31 - Cache
    automake/1.16.3:258f6f05ca54813b3d7180161753df7f9ccf7e1d - Cache
    libtool/2.4.6:5a991f5080f667ea7218726de3b757bd1e1e9afc - Cache
    m4/1.4.18:24647d9fe8ec489125dfbae4b3ebefaf7581674c - Cache

Installing (downloading, building) binaries...
m4/1.4.18: Already installed!
m4/1.4.18: Appending PATH environment variable: /home/vagrant/.conan/data/m4/1.4.18/_/_/package/24647d9fe8ec489125dfbae4b3ebefaf7581674c/bin
m4/1.4.18: Setting M4 environment variable: /home/vagrant/.conan/data/m4/1.4.18/_/_/package/24647d9fe8ec489125dfbae4b3ebefaf7581674c/bin/m4
autoconf/2.71: Already installed!
autoconf/2.71: Appending PATH env var with : /home/vagrant/.conan/data/autoconf/2.71/_/_/package/cb054d0b3e1ca595dc66bc2339d40f1f8f04ab31/bin
autoconf/2.71: Setting AC_MACRODIR to /home/vagrant/.conan/data/autoconf/2.71/_/_/package/cb054d0b3e1ca595dc66bc2339d40f1f8f04ab31/bin/share/autoconf
autoconf/2.71: Setting AUTOCONF to /home/vagrant/.conan/data/autoconf/2.71/_/_/package/cb054d0b3e1ca595dc66bc2339d40f1f8f04ab31/bin/autoconf
autoconf/2.71: Setting AUTORECONF to /home/vagrant/.conan/data/autoconf/2.71/_/_/package/cb054d0b3e1ca595dc66bc2339d40f1f8f04ab31/bin/autoreconf
autoconf/2.71: Setting AUTOHEADER to /home/vagrant/.conan/data/autoconf/2.71/_/_/package/cb054d0b3e1ca595dc66bc2339d40f1f8f04ab31/bin/autoheader
autoconf/2.71: Setting AUTOM4TE to /home/vagrant/.conan/data/autoconf/2.71/_/_/package/cb054d0b3e1ca595dc66bc2339d40f1f8f04ab31/bin/autom4te
autoconf/2.71: Setting AUTOM4TE_PERLLIBDIR to /home/vagrant/.conan/data/autoconf/2.71/_/_/package/cb054d0b3e1ca595dc66bc2339d40f1f8f04ab31/bin/share/autoconf
automake/1.16.3: Already installed!
automake/1.16.3: Appending PATH env var with : /home/vagrant/.conan/data/automake/1.16.3/_/_/package/258f6f05ca54813b3d7180161753df7f9ccf7e1d/bin
automake/1.16.3: Setting ACLOCAL to /home/vagrant/.conan/data/automake/1.16.3/_/_/package/258f6f05ca54813b3d7180161753df7f9ccf7e1d/bin/aclocal
automake/1.16.3: Setting AUTOMAKE_DATADIR to /home/vagrant/.conan/data/automake/1.16.3/_/_/package/258f6f05ca54813b3d7180161753df7f9ccf7e1d/bin/share
automake/1.16.3: Setting AUTOMAKE_LIBDIR to /home/vagrant/.conan/data/automake/1.16.3/_/_/package/258f6f05ca54813b3d7180161753df7f9ccf7e1d/bin/share/automake-1.16
automake/1.16.3: Setting AUTOMAKE_PERLLIBDIR to /home/vagrant/.conan/data/automake/1.16.3/_/_/package/258f6f05ca54813b3d7180161753df7f9ccf7e1d/bin/share/automake-1.16
automake/1.16.3: Setting AUTOMAKE to /home/vagrant/.conan/data/automake/1.16.3/_/_/package/258f6f05ca54813b3d7180161753df7f9ccf7e1d/bin/automake
automake/1.16.3: Append M4 include directories to AUTOMAKE_CONAN_INCLUDES environment variable
libtool/2.4.6: Already installed!
libtool/2.4.6: Appending PATH env: /home/vagrant/.conan/data/libtool/2.4.6/_/_/package/5a991f5080f667ea7218726de3b757bd1e1e9afc/bin
libtool/2.4.6: Setting LIBTOOLIZE env to /home/vagrant/.conan/data/libtool/2.4.6/_/_/package/5a991f5080f667ea7218726de3b757bd1e1e9afc/bin/libtoolize
libtool/2.4.6: Setting LIBTOOL_PREFIX environment variable to /home/vagrant/.conan/data/libtool/2.4.6/_/_/package/5a991f5080f667ea7218726de3b757bd1e1e9afc
libtool/2.4.6: Setting LIBTOOL_DATADIR environment variable to /home/vagrant/.conan/data/libtool/2.4.6/_/_/package/5a991f5080f667ea7218726de3b757bd1e1e9afc/bin/share
libtool/2.4.6: Setting LIBTOOL_PKGAUXDIR environment variable to /home/vagrant/.conan/data/libtool/2.4.6/_/_/package/5a991f5080f667ea7218726de3b757bd1e1e9afc/bin/share/libtool/build-aux
libtool/2.4.6: Setting LIBTOOL_PKGLTDLDIR environment variable to /home/vagrant/.conan/data/libtool/2.4.6/_/_/package/5a991f5080f667ea7218726de3b757bd1e1e9afc/bin/share/libtool
libtool/2.4.6: Setting LIBTOOL_ACLOCALDIR environment variable to /home/vagrant/.conan/data/libtool/2.4.6/_/_/package/5a991f5080f667ea7218726de3b757bd1e1e9afc/bin/share/aclocal
libtool/2.4.6: Appending ACLOCAL_PATH env: /home/vagrant/.conan/data/libtool/2.4.6/_/_/package/5a991f5080f667ea7218726de3b757bd1e1e9afc/bin/share/aclocal
libtool/2.4.6: Appending AUTOMAKE_CONAN_INCLUDES environment variable: /home/vagrant/.conan/data/libtool/2.4.6/_/_/package/5a991f5080f667ea7218726de3b757bd1e1e9afc/bin/share/aclocal
libbacktrace/cci.20210118: Applying build-requirement: libtool/2.4.6
libbacktrace/cci.20210118: Applying build-requirement: automake/1.16.3
libbacktrace/cci.20210118: Applying build-requirement: autoconf/2.71
libbacktrace/cci.20210118: Applying build-requirement: m4/1.4.18
libbacktrace/cci.20210118: WARN: Build folder is dirty, removing it: /home/vagrant/.conan/data/libbacktrace/cci.20210118/_/_/build/30b88e95da2480aa597d26d85ba6f64038dcf40f
libbacktrace/cci.20210118: Copying sources to build folder
libbacktrace/cci.20210118: Building your package in /home/vagrant/.conan/data/libbacktrace/cci.20210118/_/_/build/30b88e95da2480aa597d26d85ba6f64038dcf40f
libbacktrace/cci.20210118: Generator txt created conanbuildinfo.txt
libbacktrace/cci.20210118: Calling build()
autoreconf: export WARNINGS=
autoreconf: Entering directory '.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: /home/vagrant/.conan/data/automake/1.16.3/_/_/package/258f6f05ca54813b3d7180161753df7f9ccf7e1d/bin/aclocal --force -I config
configure.ac:33: error: Please use exactly Autoconf 2.69 instead of 2.71.
config/override.m4:12: _GCC_AUTOCONF_VERSION_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:33: the top level
autom4te: error: /home/vagrant/.conan/data/m4/1.4.18/_/_/package/24647d9fe8ec489125dfbae4b3ebefaf7581674c/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: error: /home/vagrant/.conan/data/autoconf/2.71/_/_/package/cb054d0b3e1ca595dc66bc2339d40f1f8f04ab31/bin/autom4te failed with exit status: 1
autoreconf: error: /home/vagrant/.conan/data/automake/1.16.3/_/_/package/258f6f05ca54813b3d7180161753df7f9ccf7e1d/bin/aclocal failed with exit status: 1
libbacktrace/cci.20210118:
libbacktrace/cci.20210118: ERROR: Package '30b88e95da2480aa597d26d85ba6f64038dcf40f' build failed
libbacktrace/cci.20210118: WARN: Build folder /home/vagrant/.conan/data/libbacktrace/cci.20210118/_/_/build/30b88e95da2480aa597d26d85ba6f64038dcf40f
ERROR: libbacktrace/cci.20210118: Error in build() method, line 84
    self.run("{} -fiv".format(tools.get_env("AUTORECONF")), win_bash=tools.os_info.is_windows)
    ConanException: Error 1 while executing /home/vagrant/.conan/data/autoconf/2.71/_/_/package/cb054d0b3e1ca595dc66bc2339d40f1f8f04ab31/bin/autoreconf -fiv
```

In the build output, we can see that the `Build requirements` and `Build requirements packages` call for `autoconf/2.71`, but the build fails because the `configure.ac` calls for `autoconf/2.69`

When we look at the package `conanfile.py` on conan-central, we can see that it specifies `autoconf/2.69`

```
build_requires = "autoconf/2.69"
```

Why is Conan using `autoconf/2.71` instead of `autoconf/2.69`?

Comment: Please, file this issue directly to https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues, the official support is there. Anyway, it occurs because all recipes are updated manually and sometimes, some requirements are not aligned by the same version.

Comment: @uilianries, the weird thing is that the requirements on that package seem to be fine. Do you have any idea _why_ it might be happening? I'd like to fix it instead of just opening a ticket. Also, it builds fine with other platforms/settings etc.

Comment: Update: I deleted everything in the `~/.conan/data/` directory, rebuilt everything using `conan install` with `--build=missing`, and it magically worked. I still don't know why this happened though, or if the problem is permanently resolved.

Comment: Probably environment incompatibility, as you are running CentOS and all packages are built on Ubuntu. Thanks for updating!

Comment: Should be fixed in the latest revision: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues/5608